# Visio 2016 "UML Sequence" stencil missing "Alternative fragment"

Tags: uml, microsoft-visio-2016

I'm trying to create a sequence diagram in Visio 2016 Standard, however the "alternative fragment" that would allow me to identify and describe alternative flows on the diagram does not appear in the stencil. In Visual Paradigm it'd be documented something like this: https://knowhow.visual-paradigm.com/uml/seq-diagram-combined-fragment/

In Visio I can see the obvious elements things like 'lifeline', 'activation', 'message', etc., and also a non-resizeable box labelled 'Constraint' and a line labelled 'OR constraint' but it is not at all clear how these are meant to be used.

There is no 'alternative fragment' even though it's in the Microsoft support article: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-uml-sequence-diagram-c61c371b-b150-4958-b128-902000133b26.

Can anyone please point me to where the 'Alternative fragment' element can be found, or how to use the 'Constraint' and 'OR constraint' elements? Thanks.

Comment: My apologies - this question already asked and answered (for Visio 2013) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216250/uml-diagram-shapes-missing-on-visio-2013

Answer (score 0):

A complete set of stencils for UML Sequence diagrams (UML v2.5 compliant) are downloadable from here: http://www.softwarestencils.com/uml/#Visio2013

Note these state they are for Visio 2013 but they do work with Visio 2016.